# Why wont full text search work in conjunction with tags in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

My tags won't work unless I remove search capability and vice versa. I've followed a tutorial which I've tried to modify to suit my blogs needs. The app already had the ability to search tags. The code looks like the following

```
 public function index(Request $request)
 {
        $tag = $request->get('tag');
        $data = $this->dispatch(new TagIndexData($tag));
        $layout = $tag ? Tag::layout($tag) : 'tags.layouts.index';
        return view($layout, $data);
 }
```

I've modified it, by adding a search capability and the code looks like the following

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('q');

    $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
            ->orwhere('subtitle', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();

    $videos = Video::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
        ->orwhere('subtitle', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();

        $tag = $request->get('tag');
        $data = $this->dispatch(new TagIndexData($tag));
        $layout = $tag ? Tag::layout($tag) : 'tags.layouts.index';

        return view($layout, $data)->withPosts($posts)->withVideos($videos);
}
```

When I modify it, the search works but the ability to use the tags no longer works. When I click on a tag, it returns everything. Also here is my TagIndexData

```
<?php
 namespace App\Jobs;

 use App\Post;
 use App\Video;
 use App\Tag;
 use Carbon\Carbon;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

 class TagIndexData extends Job implements SelfHandling
{
protected $tag;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param string|null $tag
 */
public function __construct($tag)
{
    $this->tag = $tag;
}

/**
 * Execute the command.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function handle()
{
    if ($this->tag) {
        return $this->tagIndexData($this->tag);
    }

    return $this->normalIndexData();
}

/**
 * Return data for normal index page
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function normalIndexData()
{
    $posts = Post::with('tags')
        ->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
        ->where('is_draft', 0)
        ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
        ->simplePaginate(config('blog.posts_per_page'));

    $videos = Video::with('tags')
        ->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
        ->where('is_draft', 0)
        ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
        ->simplePaginate(config('blog.posts_per_page'));

    return [
        'title' => config('tags.title'),
        'subtitle' => config('tags.subtitle'),
        'posts' => $posts,
        'videos' => $videos,
        'page_image' => config('home.page_image'),
        'meta_description' => config('home.description'),
        'reverse_direction' => false,
        'tag' => null,
    ];
}
/**
 * Return data for a tag index page
 *
 * @param string $tag
 * @return array
 */
protected function tagIndexData($tag)
{
    $tag = Tag::where('tag', $tag)->firstOrFail();
    $reverse_direction = (bool)$tag->reverse_direction;


    $posts = Post::where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
        ->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tag) {
            $q->where('tag', '=', $tag->tag);
        })
        ->where('is_draft', 0)
        ->orderBy('published_at', $reverse_direction ? 'asc' : 'desc')
        ->simplePaginate(config('blog.posts_per_page'));
    $posts->addQuery('tag', $tag->tag);


    $videos = Video::where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
        ->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tag) {
            $q->where('tag', '=', $tag->tag);
        })
        ->where('is_draft', 0)
        ->orderBy('published_at', $reverse_direction ? 'asc' : 'desc')
        ->simplePaginate(config('blog.posts_per_page'));
    $videos->addQuery('tag', $tag->tag);


    $page_image = $tag->page_image ?: config('tags.page_image');


    return [
        'title' => $tag->title,
        'subtitle' => $tag->subtitle,
        'posts' => $posts,
        'videos' => $videos,
        'page_image' => $page_image,
        'tag' => $tag,
        'reverse_direction' => $reverse_direction,
        'meta_description' => $tag->meta_description ?:
            config('blog.description'),
      ];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use an if statement like so

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($query = $request->get('q') )
    {
        $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
            ->orwhere('subtitle', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();

        $videos = Video::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
            ->orwhere('subtitle', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();

        $tag = $request->get('tag');
        $data = $this->dispatch(new TagIndexData($tag));
        $layout = $tag ? Tag::layout($tag) : 'tags.layouts.index';

        return view($layout, $data)->withPosts($posts)->withVideos($videos);
    } else {
        $tag = $request->get('tag');
        $data = $this->dispatch(new TagIndexData($tag));
        $layout = $tag ? Tag::layout($tag) : 'blog.layouts.index';

        return view($layout, $data);
    }
```

Then it worked. It still looks messy. If someone has a suggestion to make this neater I'm open to suggestions thanks